# how to skip order by in a sql query which is taking long time in oracle 12c?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization, oracle12c

how to skip order by in a sql query which is taing long time in oracle 12c and that order by column already having index.

Comment: Are you not able to change the query?  Can you give us some context here?

Comment: If you need results in a particular order, `ORDER BY` is the only means to guarantee that ordering. If you don't need the results in a particular order then... delete the `ORDER BY` clause. Not sure what else you're looking for here?

Comment: Where is the query, the tables DDL , the problem and the requirement ? Because it's really hard to help you without them.

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever: Thanks for your comment. I need the results in particular order and applied the index eventhough it is taking time.

Comment: If you need the results in a specific order there is  no way you can get rid of the `order by`. If you need help tuning you query, please **[edit]** your question add the query, the table definitions as `create table` statements (including all indexes) and the execution plan. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try USE

```
CHARINDEX([field you want to order],'index/char that you want to order')
```